# Dynamically shape url from object

Tags: javascript

I have some data collected in the object, and this data updated dynamically. The point is that I have dynamically shape url from this data.

```
let myObj = {
    val1: 'someVal1',
    val2: 'someVal2',
    val3: [10, 39]
}

let myUrl = 'api/?conf&val1=someVal1&val2=someVal2&val3=10-39&some_other_data'
```

I need dynamically send a new request when the object gets new values

Comment: You'll need a method to compare your object with the new one, but, for me to be able to answer properly, can you show the code snippest where you are using the object and wheen it gets updated?

Comment: you mean to say that every time the object 'myObj' is changed, you want to change the 'myUrl' too?

Comment: how you are invoking the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to transform the object into the url string as follows:

```js
let myObj = {
    val1: 'someVal1',
    val2: 'someVal2',
    val3: [10, 39],
    val4: 'test&test'
};

const myUrl = Object.keys(myObj).reduce((url, key) => {
    const param = Array.isArray(myObj[key])
        ? myObj[key].join('-')
        : myObj[key];
    return [
        url,
        [key, encodeURIComponent(param)].join('=')
    ].join('&')
}, 'api/?conf');

console.log(myUrl);
```

This approach gives you the ability to have an arbitrary number of parameters in `myObj`.

Comment: If there is `&` or other characters in any of the values, they need to be encoded. Otherwise it will create invalid URL

Comment: Hi @adiga, thanks, I have updated the answer by adding `encodeURIComponent` to encode values

Answer (score 2):

All of the answers (currently 4 of them) explain various ways in which you can shape the URL string with injected parameters.

They are all legitimate ways, but I think from reading your question that aside from reshaping the string, you also need to listen to changes on the actual object containing the parameters.

I would argue that the best way to go about this would be to listen to a reply from the server that will launch run a function:

```
const setUrl(res){
  myObj.val1 = res.val1;
  myObj.val2 = res.val2;
  myObj.val3 = res.val3;

  url = // Whatever method you want to use to set the url.
}
```

However, since you didn't say you do something like this on the code, I will add that you can also "listen" to changes on the object itself, and trigger a different `setUrl()` function whenever a change occurs.

To do this:

```
// Make an Object:
const obj = {};

// Make a url variable:
let url = '';

// Make a function to set url:
const setUrl = ()=>{
  url = `http://www.example.com?val1=${obj.val1}&val2=${obj.val2}`; // Or whatever method you prefer to build the string.
}

// Make an Object Proxy and inject it with the setUrl() method:
const objProx = new Proxy(obj, {
  set(obj, prop, newVal) {
    // Here you inject some action to take place whenever the set method is invoked on the obj via the proxy.
    setUrl();
    return obj[prop] = newVal;
  },
});

// Now all that is left to do is make sure that you set the properties of obj via the objProxy:
objProxy.val1 = "parameter1";
objProxy.val2 = "parameter2";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let myObj = {
    val1: 'someVal1',
    val2: 'someVal2',
    val3: [10, 39]
}

let myUrl = `api/?conf&val1=${myObj["val1"]}&val2=${myObj["val2"]}&val3=${myObj["val3"].join("-")}&some_other_data`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Syntax) where expressions in back ticks are evaluated:

```js
let myObj = {
  val1: 'someVal1',
  val2: 'someVal2',
  val3: [10, 39]
};

let myUrl = `api/?conf&val1=${encodeURIComponent(myObj.val1)}&val2=${encodeURIComponent(myObj.val1)}&&val3=${encodeURIComponent(myObj.val3.join("-"))}&&some_other_data`;
console.log(myUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

- Loop through the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object
- Check if the `value` is an array using [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)
- If yes, join the array with `-` and append the key and joined string value to `searchParams`
- Else, simply [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) key and value to `searchParams`

Use [`URLSearchParams.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString) to get the query string

```js
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
let myObj = {
  val1: 'someVal1',
  val2: 'someVal2',
  val3: [10, 39]
}

Object.entries(myObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if(Array.isArray(value))
    searchParams.append(key, value.join('-'))
  else
    searchParams.append(key, value)
})

console.log(searchParams.toString())
```